# Compiling Assembly Manually

Tags: compilation, assembly

I am having trouble with translating a specific line in assembly to machine code for the [Nios II](http://www.altera.com/literature/hb/nios2/n2cpu_nii5v1.pdf).
I have successfully compiled these lines:

```
START_TIMER = 0xF68C
r0 = 0x0
r8 = 0x8
label = 50000

#orhi r8, r0, %hiadj(label) --> 00000 01000 ???????????????? 110010
addi r8, r8, %lo(label) --> 01000 01000 1100001101010000 000100
subi r8, r8, 1 --> 01000 01000 1111111111111111 000100
bne r8, r0, START_TIMER --> 01000 00000 1111011010001100 011110
```

The line in question that I have trouble with is IMM16 in this one:

```
orhi r8, r0, %hiadj(label)
```

As explained in the handbook linked above, "%lo" means "Extract bits [15..0] of immed32" and "%hiadj" means "Extract bits [31..16] and adds bit 15 of immed32". However, 50000 in binary is 1100001101010000, and is therefore a 16 bit number. As far as I can see, it doesn't contain any bits between 16 and 31. I tried with 0000000000000001, but it's incorrect.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**
Just to clear any misunderstandings; I only wonder how to **manually compile "orhi r8, r0, %hiadj(label)"**. The variables "r8", "r0" and "label" are as described above and do not change.

**Edit 2:**
What I've tried is to turn 50000 into a 32 bit binary:

```
00000000000000001100001101010000
```

...extract bit [31...16]:

```
0000000000000000
```

...add bit 15 (this is confusing, since they don't tell me if it's worth 2^15 or 2^0, I've tried both and simply not to add at all)

```
0000000000000001
1000000000000000
0000000000000000
```

All are incorrect.

**Edit 3:**
According to [this link](http://www.vxdev.com/docs/vx55man/diab5.0ppc/c-asse_e.htm#3000148), when the 16 bit value is 0x8000 or more, it sign-extends the rest to 0xffff8000 and adds 1 to bits [31...16], which overloads the number to 0x100008000 ~ 0x00008000, which is what you said, Jerald, but apparently still not correct.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided takes the value at "label", which is a 16-bit halfword, and extends it to a 32-bit word to become an address.  Since your label is a 16-bit value, you must shift zeros into the upper half of the register.

So what you want to do is load zeros into the upper bits, then add in the lower bits...

```
orhi  r8, r0, %hiadj(label) --> 00000 01000 0000000000000000 110010
addi  r8, r8, %lo(label) --> 01000 01000 1100001101010000 000100
```

Comment: "orhi" and "addi" are part of the pseudo instruction "movia" (movia r8,50000), so it occurs directy before "addi". There are no other instructions provided for me than these four, so it isn't a complete program, just a snippet. 

When you say "shift bits up to [31...16]", do you mean that I should turn it into 11000011010100000000000000000000? I'm quite new to programming in assembly, so please bear with me.

Comment: Thank you, but that's not correct either. I'm puzzled, since it says "extract bits [31...16] (which are all zeroes) and add bit 15". Since bit 15 is already 1, it should carry over to bit 16, and therefore be 000000000000001, but neither is that correct...

Comment: The 0xFFFF is a signed 16-bit number, so it's really -1.  Adding the high bit of the lower 16-bit number will just be -1 + 1 = 0.  So there are your zeroes for the high 16 bits again.


I see your r8 register holds a value 0x08.  Do you mean to do this, or should it be 0x00?  Having bit 3 set when you "or" the register will leave bit 3 set.

Comment: I am so sorry, I made a simple mistake when entering the numbers. You were correct. Thank you :]